# OS X El Capitan deny copy file to Safari directory

Tags: macos, safari

In older OS X versions I can copy a file by dragging it to Safari directory like the picture below shows. But it doesn't work in El Capitan:

[image]
So I open Console, sudo to root use [copy] command to copy, but It show below alert:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to work you have to disable System Integrity Protection.

The SRI feature denies you from writing into System Protected folders ([info](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)):

> Paths and applications protected by System Integrity Protection
>   include:
>
> - /System
> - /usr
> - /bin
> - /sbin
>
> Apps that are pre-installed with OS X Paths and applications that
>   third-party apps and installers can write to include:
>
> - /Applications
> - /Library
> - /usr/local